# slideToggle doesn't push next div?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some slideToggle's on my page, and they are under each other in the HTML.

like:

```
<div>Show/hide</div>
<div>Content to be displayed</div>

<div>Show/hide</div>
<div>Content to be displayed</div>
```

And I want the contentDiv to push the next ones when opened - but no. I thought this was part of the slideToggle function.

What's wrong here?

EDIT: **FIXED**

Comment: nvm, My fault. Had some div inside of a 'foreach' which made it create the 'main div' everytime I had a new result from the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it my self, I had an error in the code is described in the comments to the question.